# Generics cannot cast Object to interface class java

Tags: java, generics

I thought to use [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library to get the class that implements a manager with a specific annotation value.

I wrote the code like this:

```
public enum Reflection {

    INSTANCE;

    Reflection() {
        managersRef = new Reflections("com.company.manager");
    }

    private final Reflections managersRef;

    public Manager getManagerImplWithName(String name, Class<? extends Manager> subType) {
            Set<?> managers = managersRef.getSubTypesOf(subType);
            for (Object clazz : managers) {
                Service serviceAnno = ((Class<?>) clazz).getAnnotation(Service.class);
                if (serviceAnno != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(serviceAnno.name()) && serviceAnno.name().equals(name))
                    return (Manager) clazz;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Manager is an interface.
SubType is class that implements Manager e.g. ProductManager/OfficeManager

I am looking for any class that implements it with annotation @Service(name=name).

This works fine until the line return (Manager) clazz. I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to com.mycompany.manager.Manager
```

What is wrong? In the inspect I can see that the type of clazz is ProductManager that implements Manager

Comment: You have not given us enough details to solve the issue. What is `managersRef`? Where is the method `getSubTypeOf` declared?

Comment: I edited the code. Reflections is https://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Comment: I believe, you want an instance of `Manager`, but what you have is a `Class` object.

Comment: Correct. I want an instance of Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `Class` object into an instance of that class. I'm not sure that is really what you want to do, but you can create an instance from the `Class` object.

```
public Manager getManagerImplWithName(String name, Class<? extends Manager> subType) {
    Set<?> managers = managersRef.getSubTypesOf(subType);
    for (Object clazz : managers) {
        Service serviceAnno = ((Class<?>) clazz).getAnnotation(Service.class);
        if (serviceAnno != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(serviceAnno.name()) && serviceAnno.name().equals(name))
            return (Manager) ((Class<?>) clazz).newInstance();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I get "the method newInstance() is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: I get: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type capture#2-of ? to Class<?>" on the for loop line

Comment: you get this when you call newInstance?

Comment: Try casting the object before calling newInstance.

Comment: @Dejel `managers` should be declared as `Set<? extends Class<? extends Manager>>` instead. Then `for (Class<? extends Manager> clazz : managers)` and `return clazz.newInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of `Class<Manager>` representing objects which tell you something *about* the class `Manager`, instances of `Manager` representing manager objects - clearly, they are not the same and cannot be cast into one another.